# How to preserve Recycler View content and scroll position in a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a list fragment (containing RecyclerView) and a details fragment. When navigating from list fragment to details fragment and then back to list fragment (using navigation component), the RecyclerView in the list fragment gets recreated which in my case is a bit expensive task and also the scroll position is lost. How can I save the RecyclerView contents and it's scroll position and prevent it from recreating when navigating back to list fragment...